# Integrate Spring Socials (Facebook) with Spring MVC XML Based

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-social

I have a working spring mvc webapp and it is xml based so i have to use the same procedures and not "pure java configs".

I'm trying to integrate facebook sign in to my app and i have tried to follow many tutorials but couldn't manage to make them work.

Here is one of my tries: (https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-facebook/)

**EDIT:**

My XML is now this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:facebook="http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/facebook"
    xmlns:twitter="http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/twitter"
    xmlns:social="http://www.springframework.org/schema/social"
    xmlns:linkedin="http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/linkedin"
    xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/facebook http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/spring-social-facebook.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/linkedin http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/spring-social-linkedin.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/twitter http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/spring-social-twitter.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/social http://www.springframework.org/schema/social/spring-social.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop  http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd">

        <bean id="connectionFactoryLocator" 
              class="org.springframework.social.connect.support.ConnectionFactoryRegistry">
            <property name="connectionFactories">
                <list>

                    <bean class="org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookConnectionFactory">
                        <constructor-arg value="${facebook.clientId}" />
                        <constructor-arg value="${facebook.clientSecret}" />                
                    </bean>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="usersConnectionRepository" 
              class="org.springframework.social.connect.jdbc.JdbcUsersConnectionRepository">
            <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
            <constructor-arg ref="connectionFactoryLocator" />
            <constructor-arg ref="textEncryptor" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="connectionRepository" factory-method="createConnectionRepository" 
              factory-bean="usersConnectionRepository" scope="request">
            <constructor-arg value="#{request.userPrincipal.name}" />
            <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="false" />
        </bean>

        <bean class="org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController">
            <!-- relies on by-type autowiring for the constructor-args -->
        </bean>

        <bean class="org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController">
            <!-- relies on by-type autowiring for the constructor-args -->
            <property name="applicationUrl" value="${application.url}" />
        </bean>



    <facebook:config app-id="962223610477458" app-secret="b7dfec28b08ac4e8c2a09cbac4662c15" app-namespace="setelog_selectandwin" />

</beans>
```

HomeController:

@Controller
public class HomeController {

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

private Facebook facebook;
private ConnectionRepository connectionRepository;

@Inject
public HomeController(Facebook facebook, ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
    this.facebook = facebook;
    this.connectionRepository = connectionRepository;
}

/**
 * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
     if (connectionRepository.findPrimaryConnection(Facebook.class) == null) {
            return "redirect:/connect/facebook";
        }

        model.addAttribute("facebookProfile", facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile());
        PagedList<Post> feed = facebook.feedOperations().getFeed();
        model.addAttribute("feed", feed);
        return "facebook/hello";
}
```

}

NOW the error is
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'scopedTarget.connectionFactoryLocator' is defined

If I remove th facebook:config tag it gives me the following error because there is no such bean:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.springframework.social.facebook.api.Facebook] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which version of spring framework do you use?

Answer (score 2):

You need not add spring's facebook interface as class in your xml. Instead create FacebookConnectionFactory using your facebook client id and secret using xml or java code.

```
@Configuration
public class SocialConfig implements SocialConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addConnectionFactories(ConnectionFactoryConfigurer cfConfig, Environment env) {
        cfConfig.addConnectionFactory(new FacebookConnectionFactory(
            env.getProperty("facebook.clientId"),
            env.getProperty("facebook.clientSecret")));
    }

    ...
}
```

or

Using Spring Social Facebook’s XML configuration namespace:

```
<facebook:config app-id="${facebook.clientId}"
                 app-secret="${facebook.clientSecret}"
                 app-namespace="socialshowcase" />
```

Refer : [Spring Social Facebook Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social-facebook/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/)

Comment: Adding to what @EvaMariam already mentioned. checkout the following xml configuration https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples/blob/master/attic/spring-social-showcase-xml/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/social.xml

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions guys and @shazin that link was really helpfull but still can't get it to work. I have updated my question.

Comment: Updated my question with that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

taken from spring social quickstart example. Probably you cant inject it by yourself, instead you have to use factory-like method:

```
@Bean
@Scope(value="request", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)   
public Facebook facebook() {
    return connectionRepository().getPrimaryConnection(Facebook.class).getApi();
}
```

it needs other dependencies, no point to copy-paste them all here. Take a look at: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples/blob/master/spring-social-quickstart/src/main/java/org/springframework/social/quickstart/config/SocialConfig.java